# Error when iterating arraylist with points of lines to check for intersection

Tags: java, android, math

I'm developing some code to check for intersection between lines. I have all points of the lines stored in an arraylist and below I have some code to iterati throw the arraylist to compare two lines at the time. But I get an error message from this line: `Line line2 = new Line(points.get(j), points.get(j+1));` It's the `j+1` that causes the error. If I just have `j` then it's no problem, but then I don't get the next point!? Can't I do it like this or have I been thinking wrong in some way? Help is preciated to locate the error or suggestion alternative solution.

```
    // Intersection control
    if(touchActionUp) {

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size()-3; i++) {
            Line line1 = new Line(points.get(i), points.get(i+1));

            for (int j = i + 2; j < points.size(); j++) {
                Line line2 = new Line(points.get(j), points.get(j+1));

                // Call method to check intersection
                if(checkIntersection(line1, line2)) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem:

```
for (int j = i + 2; j < points.size(); j++) {
    Line line2 = new Line(points.get(j), points.get(j+1));
```

That will keep incrementing until *and including* `j = points.size() - 1` at which point calling `points.get(j+1)` will be effectively calling `points.get(points.size())` which is an invalid index.

You just want a smaller lower bound:

```
for (int j = i + 2; j < points.size() - 1; j++) {
```

It *looks* to me like you're not using the list of points correctly though - if you're trying to use *pairs* of points in the list, then `i++` and `j++` should be `i += 2` and `j += 2` - otherwise you're going to create lines from points with indexes of (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3) etc. *Maybe* that's your intention - if these are meant to be lines describing a single shape, for example... but if it's not, I'd encourage you to create a `List<Line>` instead, where each `Line` has a pair of points. That will be simpler to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the end I want to check for intersection and compare two line segemts at the time. All lines are line segments of a path that has been drawn with the onTouch method. The first loop will iterate all points except for the last 3. And the second loop will start after the first line and then check the rest.  I use the arraylist to store each point while the finger moves on the screen. Was this comment helpful?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Okay, that makes more sense. All you told us in the question was that you had lines - if you've got a *path* made of lines (so the end of one is the start of another) that makes more sense. Have you tried my fix yet?

Comment: Seems to be new problems! After I changed to i+=2 and j+=2, the LogCat is running all the time! has it become an eternal loop? I stopped the app running on my device, but it's seems like it still running in background!?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should only change this line: for (int j = i + 2; j < points.size() - 1; j++) { and not i++ and j++ to i +=2 and j +=2? No it seems like it's working, the iterating part! Now I have to solve the intersection calculation and I'm not good in math! :(